# Apple ID won't show correctly in Keychain Access

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id, password, keychain

I was going through keychain access sorting through passwords and such and I came across a strange problem. I clicked my email (for Apple ID) and I hit "Show Password", I then entered my admin, and when the password came out it was a list of numbers not my password. I know my Apple ID password, but for some reason I am very bugged by this and wanted answers :)! Haha Thanks to all who respond for my OCD's sake...

Comment: Precisely which keychain entry did you check? A lot of the tokens are machine controlled, not human, & don't show anything like your actual password.

Comment: @Tetsujin in the "login tab" I pressed my email with the account as a number, kind: application password, where: icloud. If this is the wrong one please tell me!

Answer (score 1):

Apple stores a hash or key so that people’s accounts won’t be compromised.

You’ll need to find another place it’s stored to look up that password.